# PHP User Login System Issue - Only last user can log in

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a login system using php. What I am trying to create is to have a page that ask for username, password, email. Then when the user fill in the fields to go to the next page where the user will be asked to put his username and password in order to login to the system. Moreover, I have created something but is not working properly. The form is submitted correctly and I receive the data into my database but when the user tries to login into the system it will only allow the LAST user that registered, to login with his credentials into the system. For all the other users that are registered also, the login is not working. Please can someone help to solve this issue?

Thanks.

My HTML and PHP Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Please sign in with your username<br>
            and password to complete the form... Thanks!!!</h2>
            <form method="post" action="success.php">

               <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

                        $username = $_POST['user_username'];
                        $password = $_POST['user_password'];


                        $query = "SELECT * FROM users_info";

                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $db_username = $row['user_username'];
                             $db_password = $row['user_password'];
                        }

                        if($username !== $db_username) {
                            echo "Username does not exist";
                        }else if ($password !== $db_password) {
                            echo "Password does not exist";
                        }else {
                            header("Location: form.php");
                        }

                    }
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="user_username">Enter Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="user_username">Enter Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: You're selecting ***all*** users from your database, then assign them all to `$db_username` (so only the last one remains after the loop)… That's insane to begin with. Select only the one user you're actually interested in from your database using `WHERE user_username = ...`!

Comment: Because you query ALL the users `SELECT * FROM users_info` and loop through them, so only the last is saved in your variables `$db_username` and `$db_password`.

Comment: You need to learn some programming basics before you start asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit the query to pull only the user information that is attempting to log in. Note, this doesn't cover the incoming comments about SQL Safety or error reporting. I strongly suggest you do error checking to see if the fetched results are empty, then move forward.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>Please sign in with your username<br>
            and password to complete the form... Thanks!!!</h2>
            <form method="post" action="success.php">

               <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

                        $username = $_POST['user_username'];
                        $password = $_POST['user_password'];


                        //Fetch matching user data
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE user_username = '$username' AND user_password = '$password'";

                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $db_username = $row['user_username'];
                             $db_password = $row['user_password'];
                        }

                        if($username !== $db_username) {
                            echo "Username does not exist";
                        }else if ($password !== $db_password) {
                            echo "Password does not exist";
                        }else {
                            header("Location: form.php");
                        }

                    }
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="user_username">Enter Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="user_username">Enter Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should at least provide a solution that is not SQL injection cliche no. 1 :D

Comment: Thanks guys for ur help. @Adam A your answer in what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, @xander, hopefully the OP understands the risks and utilizes this to dig into more secure methods.

Comment: I have used while loop to fetch all rows from DB

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a condition inside your loop. Because what you are doing is wrong. Please get in touch with more PHP basics and some basic login systems.

Your SQL-Query should be look like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE user_username ='". mysqli_real_escape_string(CONNECTION_VAR, $username). "' AND user_password ='". mysqli_real_escape_string(CONNECTION_VAR, $password ). "' LIMIT 1";

CONNECTION_VAR - your connection id to the database
```

So you get only one row, if it matches (the password and user name). You can easily fetch it like this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

So you can work with the data in `$row`.

But please have attention to the following:

1. get in touch with basic php
2. get in touch with basic (My)SQL stuff
3. crypt/encrypt and hash passwords. Do NEVER use clear passwords in the database

Also learn how to use mysql classes.

Simple Login/Register system: http://codingcyber.com/simple-user-registration-script-in-php-and-mysql-84/
 - But please keep in mind of hashing or salting the password. Also escape everthing before using data in a query!

Comment: Ok @yfain. Thank you for your advice.